# Vary coefficient in system of equation in Matlab's fsolve

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to solve the following two equations using `fsolve`:

```
  p*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1))=0 .... (1)

  -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))=0.....(2)
```

where "p" is the coefficient that I want to vary from -3 to +3, i.e., `-3:0.1:3`. This works if the value of `p` is manually specified each time, as below:

```
x=fsolve(@myfun,x0)

function F = myfun(x)
    F = [-3*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
    -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];
```

Can Matlab vary the value of `p` automatically?

Comment: Rather than change it in the code of `myfun` each time? You could do `function F = myfun(x,p), F = [p*x(1) ...` and then call fsolve as `p = 3; fsolve(@(x)myfun(x,p), x0)`

Comment: ithanks Sean , i want p to be -3 ,-2,-1,0,1,2,3  .can it be done in one go ?how should i define p for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line using `arrayfun`, though it looks kind of convoluted and simply looping over `p` might be faster:

```
function F = myfun(x,p)
F = [p*x(1) - x(2) - exp(-x(1));
     -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(-x(2))];

p_values = -3:.1:3;
x = arrayfun(@(p)fsolve(@(x)myfun(x,p), x0), p_values, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

and `x` is then an cell array containing the different answers. `x{1}` contains the solution at `p = p_values(1)`, etc.

To make `x` a matrix with each column a solution (i.e. `x(:,1)` is the solution with `p = p_values(1)`), just call `cell2mat`:

```
x = cell2mat(x);
```

Comment: Thanks Sean ,it worked very well  . can i get output  x(1),x(2)  in different columns or rows ,because i want to use x(1),x(2) individually in further calculations .

Comment: Thanks thanks dear  bro  for your help . Sat sri akaal